# Output redirection using a bash variable

Tags: bash

I would like to do something along these lines, but most combinations I have tried have failed:

```
export no_error="2 > /dev/null"
./some_command $no_error
```

To run that command and redirect the output using a variable instead of typing the command. How would I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shell doesn't re-evaluate your `no_error` variable when you use it like that.  It just gets passed to `./some_command` as a command-line argument.  You can get the behaviour you want by using `eval`.  From the [`bash` manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html):

> `eval [arguments]`
>
> The arguments are concatenated together into a single command, which is then read and executed, and its exit status returned as the exit status of `eval`. If there are no arguments or only empty arguments, the return status is zero.

Here's an example for your case:

```
export no_error="2>/dev/null"
eval ./some_command $no_error
```

Note that you can't have a space between the `2` and the `>`.  I'm guessing that's just a typo in your question, though.